# The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin

I'm integrating google sign in in my Swift project, it's getting some error.

```
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GIDSignIn error -4.)
```

I followed this link : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating?refresh=1

My code is : In **AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // Initialize sign-in
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "15084783084-s3siolgukj7ikgqhfgcvo2e7i4jb9.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    private func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    }

    private func application(application: UIApplication,
                 openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any?) -> Bool {
         var _: [String: AnyObject] = [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication.rawValue: sourceApplication as AnyObject,
                                        UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation.rawValue: annotation as AnyObject]
        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                annotation: annotation)
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
            let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
            let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
            let fullName = user.profile.name
            let givenName = user.profile.givenName
            let familyName = user.profile.familyName
            let email = user.profile.email
            // ...
        }
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!,
          withError error: Error!) {
        // Perform any operations when the user disconnects from app here.
        // ...
    }
}
```

In **ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

    }

    @IBAction func onClickGoogleSignIn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()

        //        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()

    }

}
```

My requirement is when click on sign in button i want to login

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `SignIn` method,

use this code:

```
@IBAction func onClickGoogleSignIn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut() //if already signed in, then sign out and have fresh sign in again
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

instead of

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you Mehul Thakkar. It's working, is it possible to collet user complete details like registered mobile number, DOB etc

Comment: You can access only name, email, accessTokens, id etc. For getting more details like DOB, mobileNumber etc, you have to add more scopes in GIDSignIn before logging in. You can refer this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in

Comment: Instead of assigning clientId and delegate in AppDelegate, move that code into your viewController.swift. By this way, your delegate code will be there in viewController.swift. So, on success, you can move to next VC

Comment: Simply saying... move full code of GoogleSignIn from `AppDelegate` to your `ViewController.swift`. This will work for you.

Comment: Ok, right thank you very much to spent your valuable time for me.

Comment: In AppDelegate... keep only `openURL` methods code of GoogleSignIn

Comment: One more mistake in your code - you kept, 2 `openURL` methods in your `AppDelegate`. Out of this 2, one is for iOS 7 and previous versions. So, if you are not giving support to those versions, then remove that method

Comment: didSignInFor, didDisconnectWith are from appdelegate to VC am I right

Comment: Yes, Full `GIDSignInDelegate` should be moved to your ViewController

Comment: Yes, you are right I will remove second openURL function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185972/discussion-between-ios-and-mehul-thakkar).